# How to get Web service response in an iOS app when application is in Background?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, background, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I am working on an iOS application in which I am using Restful web service by `NSURLConnection`, when I call web service and after calling web service press home button then application goes in to background and it is not getting response in background. In my application response should get even when application will be in background state.

So please suggest me any suitable answer for this.

Should I use `NSURLSession` ?

Comment: Yes. It was designed exactly for that.

Comment: @KPM please, tell how can I do this

Comment: See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24428534/364446

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@""]; // set your url here
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *getTask = [session downloadTaskWithURL:myURL completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // do stuff with the result
}];

// don't forget to start your task 
[getTask resume];
```

Here's a nice tutorial you might want to take: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial

Answer (score -1):

Use UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier, something like this

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

  //Start Background Service and get data every 10 second
  [self runBackgroundTask:10];
  }
- (void)runBackgroundTask: (int) time{

  UIApplication *app;
  app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
  //check if application is in background mode
  if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

  ```
  //create UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier and create tackground task, which starts after time
  __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
       [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
       bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
  }];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSTimer *refreshTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time target:self selector:@selector(doRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
      [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:refreshTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

      [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
      bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
  });
  ```

  }
  }

doRefresh - This is method where you give your web service

Comment: This is not the proper way to do it. Use `NSURLSession` instead, it's meant for that.

Comment: @KPM  Yes we can use NSURLSession but I think NSURLSession is used only from iOS 7, is it right?

Comment: You didn't specify anything regarding the need for pre-iOS 7 compatibility.